# Convert Sql query with Group by and Having clause to Linq To Sql query in C#

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I need help to convert following ql query to Linq to Sql query.

```
select Name, Address
from Entity
group by Name, Address
having count(distinct LinkedTo) = 1
```

Idea is to find all unique Name, Address pairs who only have 1 distinct LinkedTo value. Remember that there are other columns in the table as well.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
Entity.GroupBy(e => new { e.Name, e.Address})
      .Where(g => g.Select(e => e.LinkedTo).Distinct().Count() == 1)
      .Select(g => g.Key);
```

You should put a breakpoint after that line and check the SQL that is generated to find what is really going to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
from ent in Entities
group ent by new { ent.Name, ent.Address } into grouped
where grouped.Select(g => g.LinkedTo).Distinct().Count() == 1
select new { grouped.Key.Name, grouped.Key.Address }
```

The generated SQL does not use a `having` clause.  I'm not sure LINQ can generate that.